# python, trac, apache, mod_wsgi on windows

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, trac

I'm using trac 1.2 on windows. [Their documentation](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall#MandatoryDependencies) says it requires python2, so I `pip install`'d it with python2 x64, and spent a lot of time configuring some trac environments. Now I want to run trac through apache httpd so I can set it up with microsoft active directory, so I figured, okay, let's try mod_wsgi. I read [this mod_wsgi documentation](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst) which mentions that python2 is built with VC9, and that apache, mod_wsgi, python binaries need to be consistent architecture throughout. So that means, for me, VC9, x64 for all. I installed the VC9 runtime from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092). For mod_wsgi, I `pip install`d it using the `mod_wsgi‑4.6.4+ap24vc9‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl` file from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi) to avoid having to install VS2008's entire toolchain. Now I guess I need apache x64 VC9. The apache binary closest to VC9 I could find was VC10 [here](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC10/) **which says it loads VC9 modules**, so I went ahead and tried it. I ran `mod_wsgi-express module-config` which gave me

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/python27/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgiNone"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/python27"
```

The first line wasn't right, since httpd complained it couldn't load the module, so I changed it to

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/python27/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.pyd"
```

I verified that that module exists at the specified path, and ran httpd which still error'd out with

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 179 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load c:/python27/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.pyd into server: The specified module could not be found.
```

So I guess the VC10 x64 apache binary I downloaded isn't backwards compatible with VC9 x64 mod_wsgi.

Does this mean I now need to build my own VC9 x64 apache binary? There must be a simpler way to achieve running trac 1.2 within an apache web server, right? Unfortunately, it's not as obvious to me. Any help is appreciated. Also, let me know if I need to clarify any other detail.

Comment: You may want to try using the [Bitnami Trac installer](https://bitnami.com/stack/trac/installer). It provides Apache. Checkout the [documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/trac/).

Comment: Oh that's useful. Probably could be mentioned in the https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall#RunningTraconaWebServer section

Comment: Ok, just confirmed that it's working and what not. Bitnami Trac installer is definitely the way to go at the moment

Comment: The Bitnami page is linked from [TracInstallPlatform](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstallPlatforms). Eventually I'm going to modify [TracInstall](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall) to move and combine the Apache server configuration info on it's own page. Also, TracInstall needs to be the canonical Unix-centric steps and we need to have a dedicated page for Trac on Windows that's been vetted by the Trac team.